# fastapi return nested model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

How can i return a nested model ?

i have a model ( Person ), this person contain car_id in another Model ( Registration ).

```py
class PersonInput(BaseModel):
    name: str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
    
    
class RegistrationInput(BaseModel):
    person_id: int
    car_id: int
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
    
def list_person(offset: int = 0, limit: int = 50,
                database: Session = Depends(get_database)):
    persons = PersonRepository(database).list_person(offset, limit)
    return persons
    

def list_all(self, offset, limit):    
    persons = self.database.query(Registration).all()
    return persons
```

I would like to get the cars related to the people in the other Registration table.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Marco",
    "cars": 0,
    "id": 3,
    "created_at": "2022-09-29T20:51:01",
    #HERE - APPEND record from registratoin table
    "cars": [
        {"car_id": 16},
        {"car_id": 9},
    ]
  }
]
```

When i query model Person append Cars from registration to the persons.